# How to mock a Rails subclass contant in Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a `BaseController` that I want to superclass other controllers with. I also superclass some controllers with the standard `ApplicationController`.

For example, I may have:

```
class AController < ApplicationController
end
```

as well as...

```
class BController < BaseController
end
```

When testing, I sometimes need to create an arbitrary "mock" or "fake" class to test before_filters, module includes, etc. I don't do this often, but on occasion it's helpful.

I created one in my specs like so:

```
class FakeController < ApplicationController
end
```

That's fine.

But now, I need to create another one of these `FakeController` classes, but this time as a subclass of my `BaseController` class.

Unfortunately the `FakeController` constant is already registered and I'm getting superclass mismatch errors.

I don't want to do something like `FakeController2` -- as I think this opens a bad can of worms.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the issue with using `FakeController2` or any other name, but the only public alternative I can think of is to introduce a module so that your second `FakeController` exists in a different namespace, as in:

```
module Foo
  class FakeController < ApplicationController
  end
end
```

There is a private method `remove_const` defined on `Kernel` which can be used to unregister a constant from an object. So, if `FakeController` is defined on `Object`, you can unregister it with the call:

```
Object.send(:remove_const, :FakeController)
```

At that point, you can define the constant again as you would if it had never never been defined in the first place.  (Remember: Ruby is an interpreted language.)

Comment: Isn't there a way of unregistering and then re-registering a constant?

Comment: Well, that removes it. How do you re-register it in the same test lifecycle?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by this follow-up question, but I updated my answer.

Comment: Removing the constant works, so I'm awarding you the answer. But it seems the larger solution to the problem is to use a rspec's anonymous controllers: http://owowthathurts.blogspot.com/2013/05/rails-rspec-anonymous-controllers.html

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to subclassing your controllers is to use the [anonymous controller mechanism](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/anonymous-controller) provided by the rspec-rails gem.